# Unable to build Xamarin.iOS in release Mode (debug is working)

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, nuget-package, mono.cecil

I am getting an build-Error "XamlCTask task failed unexpectedly" [Build-Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AG6SZ.png) when building the xamarin.ios project in release mode (with VS). Building the Xamarin.ios project in debug-mode is working and also the xamarin.android project can be build (in release and debug mode) without getting any build-errors. Building the Xamarin.ios project with "cake-build" is working for debug and for release.

I' am using the latest Visual Studio Version and all installed NuGet packages have the same version.

If you need more information, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. I've added (by accident) the NuGet-Package "XUnit" to the Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android project. Deinstalling the (not used) package solved this issues.